# jQuery scrollTo offset on page with external links to anchors on page

Tags: jquery, scrollto

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Fixed position navbar obscures anchors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9047703/fixed-position-navbar-obscures-anchors)

I have a page using scrollTo (along with a fixed header using waypoints plugin) which works fine, I'm using div ids to link to content divs on the page from a submenu.

I have another page with links directly to the content divs. The problem is, because of the fixed header, the page content falls under the header when accessed from the external links.

So I need to find a way to use scrollTo or it's companion, localScroll, to automatically, on page load, scrollTo a negative offset amount to have the top of the content div appear below the header. ( I have it working with clicks from the submenu, but how do I achieve this automatically on page load?).

I'm thinking it needs to be offset about top: -150px, but obviously will tweak it as needed once I can get it working.

You can see what I mean here:
http://pinnacleahs.com/?page_id=8#delivery-coordinators

Comment: Similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9047703/fixed-position-navbar-obscures-anchors not sure if you saw this one.

Comment: The snippet of code that was voted up on that page seemed to do the trick- thanks!

Comment: This was the code snippet from evenicoulddoit that solved my particular issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9047703/fixed-position-navbar-obscures-anchors