# Navbar hides anchors

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I'm building a rails app with Bootstrap, but the top fixed navbar hides the content I jump to via a hash anchor appending to the url. Basically I have the same problem as this post explains: [Fixed position navbar obscures anchors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9047703/fixed-position-navbar-obscures-anchors), and I tried to fix this problem with the below js codes I found on github:

```
$(document).ready(function(){    
  var shiftWindow = function() { scrollBy(0, -50) };
  if (location.hash) shiftWindow();
  window.addEventListener("hashchange", shiftWindow);
});
```

It works fine when I click the in-page link to jump to an anchor, but fails when I click a link in another page trying to redirect to a page with a hash in the url like from `http://mysite.com/` to `http://mysite.com/posts/1#comment-5`.

I cannot figure out what goes wrong with the above js code. Please help, thanks!

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem and I found the simplest solution was to wrap the anchor in a **section** tag and then change the CSS sheet to read:

```
section {
    display: block;
    padding-top: 40px;
}
```

Then you don't need any js and it will work when you jump to that section id from another page.

Comment: Did not work for me. Content is still overlapped by bootstrap menu.