# Anchor with background color under a fixed position menu

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, anchor

I want to fixed the location of link anchor in a page with fixed position menu, the question [Fixed position navbar obscures anchors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9047703/fixed-position-navbar-obscures-anchors) works for me, but the background color of the link was been expand to the height of padding, how can I change to the height of font.  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the `background-clip` property to specify whether to fill `background-color` till `padding-box` / `content-box` or `border-box`.

The default value is `border-box`. To fill only content, use `content-box`

```
background-clip: content-box;
```

[**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/metacode/YzEWz/1/)