# How to control the anchor landing position

Tags: html, scroll, anchor, fixed

We currently have the problem, that links in the form [www.example.com/#section](http://www.example.com/#section) don't jump to the right location, because we have a fixed navigation at the top which covers up the first part of the website.

```
<div id="anchorpoint">Some content here</div>
```

**How can we tell the browser to jump to the anchor position + 100px?**

Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Fixed position navbar obscures anchors](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9047703/fixed-position-navbar-obscures-anchors)

Comment: The only solution without involving JS and repositioning your elements is to put the anchor point inside the element you want to scroll to, make it absolute, give it a 100px top margin and hide it. That way, you'd actually scroll to that invisible element, making the wanted element appear right at the top.

Comment: @TelmoMarques You are right about the question. However, the answers are not satisfying there

Comment: @Shomz It works, but ONLY if you DON'T position it absolute

Answer (score 21, accepted):

**HTML** (add an additional anchor tag)

```
 <a id="anchorpoint" class="anchor"></a>
 <div>Some content here</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.anchor {
    display:block;
    padding-top:100px;
    margin-top:-100px;
 }
```

It's a slight modification of [Fixed position navbar obscures anchors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9047703/fixed-position-navbar-obscures-anchors). The advantage lies there, that you don't prepopulate padding and margin of the actual container.

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me:

```
<a href="#learnmore"><button type="button" class="large button">Click me!</button></a>
<a class="hidden-anchor" name="learnmore"></a>
```

And the css for the anchor link.

```
 .hidden-anchor {
    position: absolute;
    top: -100px;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can apply `scroll-margin-top: 100px` to the element you want to scroll to (set the value to the height of your navbar).