# How can I get my webpage to reload with the specified id parameter positioned in the middle of the page rather than the top?

Tags: javascript, html, css, url-parameters

I am trying to use a simple html script to make it so that when you reload the page with a specified id parameter, it will load with the id parameter in the middle of the page rather than how it normally loads, at the top (and highlighted in the future).

I have tried using invisible anchors, but it doesn't work for my specific site.

My initial idea was to use this script:

```
<script>
        if (window.history.replaceState) {
            window.history.replaceState(null, null, window.location.href);
        }
        
        window.onload = window.scrollTo( [id - half of the screen length] );
</script>
```

Having trouble finding the solution here

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4996330/changing-default-starting-position-of-anchor https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23581161/how-to-control-the-anchor-landing-position

Comment: Instead of `scrollTo`, you might also want to look into https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView - especially the usage with `scrollIntoViewOptions`