# HTML Links with anchor and pixel

Tags: html, tags, anchor

I am looking for a solution without javascript, where I can use an link like this:

```
<a href='#link1 +60px'>
```

This is just an example for easier understanding. So what I am trying is, that I got an anchor in my website, and the link goes to that specific point + 60px further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So far the following is the best method I could find to position the landing position w/o javascript

**HTML** (add an additional anchor tag)

```
 <!-- Actual going to here -->
 <a id="anchorpoint" class="anchor"></a>
 <!-- Display point -->
 <div>Some content here</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.anchor {
    display:block;
    padding-top:60px;
    margin-top:-60px;
 }
```

It's a slight modification of [Fixed position navbar obscures anchors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9047703/fixed-position-navbar-obscures-anchors). The advantage lies there, that you don't prepopulate padding and margin of the actual container.

Try: https://jsfiddle.net/q6yvuhao/

Answer (score 1):

This is impossible.

Your only options are JavaScript and linking explicitly to a spot (with its own ID) above where you want to link to.

Answer (score 0):

Is the anchor point invisible?  If so, add a class to the link and the following CSS:

```
a.link {
   position:relative;
   top:60px;
}

<a class="link" href='#link1'>
```