# Jump to different sections of the page when theres a fixed navbar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I have successfully gotten my page to jump to different sections on the page via buttons referencing the ID's like this

```
<button id="niftyBtn"><a href="#nifty">Things</a></button></br>
<div id="nifty">Blah</div>
```

I have several of those and they all go to the correct portion of the page. 
The problem is, there is a fixed nav that is included into the page that I can't change and the top of the sections are going behind that navbar instead of below it.

I have tried to use several different variations of a jquery solution I saw using .offset() but none of them have been effective. Any input is appreciated

Note: It behaves the exact same way when I use jQuery or javascript to jump the sections instead of href tags.

Comment: Fixed navbar will be on top of the contents that won't push the contents of the section down, quick solution add to the padding-top of each section the height of the navbar; or using js move the scroll a negative value of the height navbar

Comment: Oh man, changing the padding had actually not occured to me, I'm not sure if that'll look bad. I have tried the scrolling to a negative value with js and it didn't seem to do anything

Comment: I think this has been answered a few times already, unless I'm misreading your question:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9047703/fixed-position-navbar-obscures-anchors?rq=1

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10732690/offsetting-an-html-anchor-to-adjust-for-fixed-header

Comment: You can see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4086107/html-positionfixed-page-header-and-in-page-anchors

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a javascript solution, something as simple as this will do:

```
h2:before,h3:before,h4:before {
    content: " ";
    display: block;
    visibility: hidden;
    margin-top: -7em;
    height: 7em;
}
```

Granted, these are meant for headings, but you can substitute with a class, or IDs for the same effect. The measurements will have to be amended, of course.

BTW, why are you using `<button>` to wrap an `<a>`? That code should just be `<a href="#nifty">Things</a></br>` and if you want it to look like a button, style it like a button.

Comment: There is already styling in place for buttons on the site, so rather than repeat the styling for this page I just put an     <a> inside of it.

Comment: But I will try this, thank you :)

Comment: You wouldn't need to repeat the styling, you could just do `<a class="button">` and do `button, .button` in the CSS. Granted, having an `<a>` inside a `<button>` is valid, it's just... ugly :D

Comment: ^that is fair enough